# Getting 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed error while to created nested array dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create nested array of array inside a pandas dataframe column `df[link]` and attach back to original datframe. What's wrong with my code and how to fix this?

Error:

> TypeError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in 
> 2 df2['shipmentNumber'] = df2.shipmentID.str.split('-',1).str[-1]
> 3 df2['link'] = pd.DataFrame({'link': df2.to_dict('records')})
> ----> 4 result['link']  = df2.groupby(df2.index).agg(list)['link']
>
> c:\users\ashok.eapen\pycharmprojects\rs-components\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
> 940     def aggregate(self, func=None, *args, engine=None, engine_kwargs=None, **kwargs):
> 941
> --> 942         relabeling, func, columns, order = reconstruct_func(func, **kwargs)
> 943
> 944         if maybe_use_numba(engine):
>
> TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

My input:

```
df6

ShipmentID                                                                             CustomerCode  
['USWPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'USWPR04-20210429-S-00002','USWPR04-20210429-S-00006']    USWPR04
['MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002']                               MSLPR04
```

My code:

```
df2= df6.explode('shipmentID')
df2['shipmentNumber'] = df2.shipmentID.str.split('-',1).str[-1]
df2['link'] = pd.DataFrame({'link': df2.to_dict('records')})
result['link']  = df2.groupby(df2.index).agg(list)['link']
```

Expected output column:

```
df['LinkID']

[{ "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },
 { "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" },
 { "ShipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00006" }]

[{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },
{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" }]
```

Expected final dataframe:

```
ShipID                                                                             CustomerCode   link
['USWPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'USWPR04-20210429-S-00002','USWPR04-20210429-S-00006']    USWPR04    [{ "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },{ "shipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" },{ "ShipID": "USWPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "USWPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00006" }]
['MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001', 'MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002']                               MSLPR04    [{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00001", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shiNumber": "20210429-S-00001" },{ "shipID": "MSLPR04-20210429-S-00002", "customerCode": "MSLPR04", "shipNumber": "20210429-S-00002" }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#add df2.index first
df2['link'] = pd.DataFrame({'link': df2.to_dict('records')}, index=df2.index)
#assign to `df6`
df6['link'] = df2.groupby(df2.index)['link'].agg(list)
```

Or instead your solution list comprehension:

```
df6['link1'] = [[{'shipID':x, 'CustomerCode':b, 'shipmentNumber': x.split('-',1)[-1]} 
                for x in a] for a, b in zip(df6['ShipmentID'],df6['CustomerCode'])]
```

Output are same:

```
print (df6['link'] == df6['link1'])
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```